# writing a file in c++ with Xcode and running with terminal

Tags: c++, xcode

I'm very new to programming and i bought myself a self help book but the book is designed for windows. I've mostly been able to translate so far but i'm stumped on writing/appending files and running them through terminal. I was wondering if someone could translate these lines for me. these lines are what I'm told to type in command prompt/terminal.

C:\MyPrograms> c++ write.cpp -o write.exe

C:\MyPrograms> write

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
string poem = "\n\tI never saw a man who looked" ;
poem.append("\n\tWith such a wistful eye") ;
poem.append("\n\tUpon that little tent of blue") ;
poem.append("\n\tWhich prisoners call the sky") ;

ofstream writer("poem.txt") ;

if (! writer)
{
    cout << "Error opening file for output" << endl ;
    return -1 ;             //signal an error then exit the program.
}

writer << poem << endl ;            // write output
writer.close() ;                    // close filestream.

return 0 ;
}
```

This is the program i am trying to run named write.cpp please help thanks!

Comment: And what is the problems you have? What works? What doesn't work? Please elaborate!

Comment: Also, you *do* know that the "C:\" prompt and `.exe` files are used on *Windows* and not on macOS?

Comment: Are you asking how those commands should be formed to accomplish the same task on your Mac as you do on Windows. ? Just checking.

Comment: Sorry, you should really go for another book:  a c++ tutorial that in 2016 still has `#include <stdio.h>` is certainly not the best source for learning proper C++.  And if stdio would really be needed because of some legacy C functions,  in c++ it should be  `#include <cstdio>`.

Comment: @Christophe Xcode automatically puts that in there. i meant to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OS X, the first line in Terminal would be:

`g++ write.cpp -o write`

The second line would be:

`./write`

The first line compiles your code and creates an executable called `write`. The second line runs the executable.

Comment: This is what i needed but it still isn't executing any program. is there something else that needs to be done before hand? like an option to connect Xcode or terminal to a text editor to run the program? @ShadersAndTrees

Comment: it doesn't give me any feedback either in terminal it simply creates a new line

Comment: The output is a file called `poem.txt` not anything in Terminal.

Comment: @MarkSetchell okay but in the book it shows that (in the windows version) notepad pops up and shows the poem.txt file when it is run how do i get it to do that

Comment: Macs don't have `Notepad` and this program doesn't appear to open it anyway. Try `open poem.txt` in Terminal. If that works, add something like `system("open poem.txt");` near the end of your program.